# Implement Pagination in ListView in Android

Tags: android, listview, pagination

I have implemented a Customised `ListView` using `BaseAdapter` and Lazy loading concept to load the images for the list items.
I am working with the RESTFul services . The webservice method defines the no of items in each page(20 items per page) & the total no of pages present(5 pages). Now , I am able to load the first page accordingly . 
I need to call the webservice method again to download the next page contents accordingly & display it in the similar way as the first page.
Kindly provide the logic/sample source code on how to implement the pagination if anyone has already implemented.

Also , I have seen in few of the Android applications in the Android market , that the progress dialogue is displayed at the end of the list while loading the items , maybe the second page contents. 
Kindly provide hints if someone has already implemented so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Kindly provide the logic/sample source code on how to implement the pagination if anyone has already implemented.

See my [`EndlessAdapter`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless).

Comment: I went through the EndlessAdapter. Now , I need the code to be a merge of LazyListAdapter which extends BaseAdapter & EndlessAdapter which extends AdapterWrapper . The class which I was using for Lazy loading was extending BaseAdapter .I wrote the logic for the customised listview within the method public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {} . How can I add the code for EndlessAdapter within the LazyAdapter class. Is there any other way we can proceed.I need both the functionalities 1>Lazy loading of images for list items 2>Implementing pagination in Android.

Comment: @user443141: `EndlessAdapter` is designed to wrap around an existing `ListAdapter`, presumably one like this "LazyListAdapter", whatever that is. You should not need to merge the code bases. If you do, then that is up to you to figure out.

Comment: Thanks for your comments .  The problem is that my LazyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter & within the LazyListAdapter class I have the public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {} method. I am unable to get the logic from where to call the Endless Adapter to limit the no of list items & implement the pagination.

Comment: Kindly help me with the logic/sample code if someone has implemented both Lazy loading of images & pagination for list in Android

Comment: @CommonsWare, You're the best! I was looking for some good way of implementing the pagination in ListView and then I saw Your post here. I successfully ran EndlessAdapter demo and hope to use it in my app. Thank You very much!

Comment: please provide some some sample code for pagination loadmore android gridview onscrolllistener my input object contains pagenumber and results per page am able to get data but override on the existing data and when i click on listitem exception is coming please help me